# How can I force PyCharm to inspect the requirements.txt file and suggest updates?

Tags: pycharm

How can I force PyCharm to inspect the requirements.txt file and suggest updates?
I can't seem to control when this happens.
Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Open any `.py` file after `requirements.txt` has been changed, PyCharm will parse `requirements.txt` and suggest updates, e.g. packages installation.

Comment: This does not work reliably. This feature seems to require some voodoo to get it to work. Right now nothing I do can make pycharm process the requirements.txt. Can anyone explain the system/project/file states in which it works and which it does not?

Comment: @Ron Please check that `Package requirements file` field (`Settings - Tools - Python Integrated Tools`) is not empty. If it's not empty, file an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

Comment: How does this work for *anaconda's* `requirements/environment.yml` file?
I would like Pycharm to parse it automatically and install accordingly. My conda python is set as the project's interpreter.

-- EXPLANATION:
I once cloned a project that had such a file and it worked out of the box. However, when I try to recreate the behaviour, I do not succeed.

Comment: @LionelTrebuchon It is not supported yet, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19974

Comment: @user2235698 Done.

Comment: @Ron, its not voodo.
- Create a project where your python modole is the root will confiugre the requiremnt.txt as it should be, and then pycharm will detect changes.
- Create a project and import a python module, in this case the pyCharm will not detect your requiremnt.txt and you will have to configure it in Settings - Tools - Python Integrated Tools as user2235698 said

Answer (score 28):

I tried opening any .py file, checking Package requirements file field (Settings - Tools - Python Integrated Tools). Nothing triggered my PyCharm on Windows to detect a new dependency added to `requirements.txt`. Since the virtual environment was created with PyCharm's `Add Local`, trying to get `pip` to work for the virtual environment with a Windows command line also seemed quite a bit of work.

Finally, the easiest solution that worked for me was as follows.

1. Click on the icon in the lower left corner. It brings up menus to `Project`, `Python Console`, `Structure`, `TODO`, etc. Find `Terminal` in it.

   [image]
2. Click on `Terminal`. It seems to be automatically virtual environment aware.
3. Run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: @greatvovan for me it is, are you sure you have configured project interpreter?

Comment: I also had issues with the accepted answer, but explicitly dropping into the Terminal environment like this worked perfectly!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is configuring explicitely the `requirements.txt` in PyCharm, as described in [the doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-dependencies.html#configure-requirements)