# How to sync requirements.txt for pycharm venv interpreter?

Tags: pycharm

I wanted to follow [the official guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-dependencies.html), which is also Google's 1st hit, however, the tools menu does not have what it is claimed to have:

[image: tools]

So, how can I auto sync a requirements file with my venv?

Pycharm 2019.3 pro, Windows 10

Comment: Well that link you're using is for Pycharm 2020.1. Indeed do have that option under tools. I actually tried looking for you the help page of older versions and couldn't find. Seems like they only keep the latest version

Comment: Can you try `Settings -> Tools -> Python Integrated Tools -> Package requierments file`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo ok, I did it. Requirements.txt file looks the same even though I installed more packages. Should I do something more?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use `requierments` myself, but found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47784779/6045800) and thought it might be related. Hope you find a solution :) Now that I think about it a simple solution will be to update Pycharm, but of course that depends on if you can (you might be using this as part of a system or something like that which needs permissions)

Answer (score 0):

This action was introduced in PyCharm 2020.1: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18847